# How to enable Image adjustment (to set width and height) in TYPO3 v7?

Tags: image, typo3, image-resizing, typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 v7, how can I display the **height** and **width** options in Backoffice to **resize images** uploaded?

I think they should appear in the section **Image Adjustment** in "Appeareance" tab when I edit an image.

However, I only see the following options:
[Appearance options screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAQMv.png)

[image: Appearance options screenshot]

Does anyone know if I have to configure something somewhere? Any extension to install that solves this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried to give permissions to the user group, so that these fields should be allowed and visible: 
Under System->Backend Users -> Backend user groups -> Access Lists->Allowed excludefields, in Page Content selected Width (pixels)(imagewidth) and Height (pixels)(imageheight).

I have also installed the fluid_styled_content extension and added the template to my site.

But there are still no changes in the appearance options :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to deinstall EXT:gridelements. Maybe problem is there. As a admin user you don't need special permission to see fields height and width.

Comment: An extension that is currently in use depends on the extension gridelements.

When I try to uninstall I receive the following warning: 
`Cannot deactivate extension 'gridelements' - The extension(s) 't3ddy' depend on it. `

Comment: Anyway, I've uninstalled the two extensions (t3ddy and gridelements) to test, but it didn't work...